# How to get average of multiple columns in a table in Angular 10

Tags: angular, typescript

I have function that calculates sum of json data in all columns on my tables.  I want to get the average of each column, but I end up getting NaN or infinity, What am I doing wrong?

This is my implementation for getting sum

```
getSum(columnNumber) {
    let sum = 0;
    const columnNumberToPropertyMap = [
      "id",
      "teamNumber",
      "rural",
      "completed",
      "entirehouseholdabsent",
      "postponed",
      "refused",
      "vacant",
      "dwelling"     
    ];
    const property = columnNumberToPropertyMap[columnNumber];
    return this.rural.reduce((acc, curr) => {
      //const adder = Number(curr[property]) || 0;
      const adder = isNaN(Number(curr[property])) ? 0 : Number(curr[property]);
      sum = acc + adder
      return sum;
    }, 0).toFixed(2);
  }
```

this gives me the sum of all the rows in the column.

How am trying to get the average of each column

```
 getSum(columnNumber) {
        let sum = 0;
        let average = 0;

        const columnNumberToPropertyMap = [
          "id",
          "teamNumber",
          "rural",
          "completed",
          "entirehouseholdabsent",
          "postponed",
          "refused",
          "vacant",
          "dwelling"     
        ];
        const property = columnNumberToPropertyMap[columnNumber];
        return this.rural.reduce((acc, curr) => {
          //const adder = Number(curr[property]) || 0;
          const adder = isNaN(Number(curr[property])) ? 0 : Number(curr[property]);
          sum = acc + adder
          average = (sum)/adder;
          return average ;
        }, 0).toFixed(2);
      }
```

I end up with NaN or infinity at the below of each column, am assuming

> average = total of each column / no of items on each column

Comment: Have you tried logging the values of `sum`, `adder`, and `average` in you code? That could help you track the calculation

Comment: Hi @PMO1948 seen my issue, the adder has the rows, but how can i get the count of the number of rows and use it?

Comment: take your array of rows and call `.length` to get the total count. If `rural` is your array, then call `this.rural.length`

Comment: Hi @PMO1948 this is a sample code [SampleCode](https://codepen.io/remymumoh-the-bold/pen/gOLEdVV?editors=0012) , can you help me out, log the number of rows in `adder`?

Comment: `console.log('agemen.length:', agemen.length);`
Add this after printing the getSum, and you can see the total length

Comment: do you want to know the total number of rows, or the total number of rows with a non-zero value?

Comment: total number of rows and use it to get average, and how can I use the total length to get the average and return it as average instead of sum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the average, you can simply call `getSum` and then divide it by the number of rows. So, implementation would be like this:

```
getAverage(columnNumber) {
    let sum = getSum(columnNumber);
    let count = this.rural.length;
    return sum / count;
}
```

Or, in one line, `return getSum(columnNumber)/this.rural.length;`

Comment: return sum / count throws an error `The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.`

Comment: try `let sum = +getSum(columnNumber);` to turn the result into a number

Comment: when you log the result, what does it show you?

Comment: alternatively, try `let sum:number = getSum(columnNumber);` or set the return type of `getSum` to be `number`